# Determine if application has had any activity ? VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

Does anyone know of a way to detect recent activity in a VB.net windows forms application?

We have a retail store where users share floor computers, the application will be on each machine and require a log in before use. I am trying to find a way to automatically close the application if it has been idle for lets say 10 minutes.

I guess I could do something similar with the current windows log on session - set a gp that logs the user out after 10 minutes of inactivity - but if there is an easy, non memory intensive way to do it in vb.net i would rather use that method

thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When the applications starts, create a handler for the `Application.Idle` event.  Also create an object that is your 10-minute timer.  The `Appliation.Idle` event is raised every time the event queue is empty.  If you move the mouse, that raises an event.  If you press a key, that raises an event.  Note that you cannot use the `Handles` keyword with `Application.Idle`.  `Handles` only works for locally decalred objects, not static objects.

```
Public Sub MainForm_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MainForm.Load
    AddHandler System.Windows.Forms.Application.Idle, AddressOf Application_Idle
    ' TODO: Create the 10-minute timer.
End Sub

Private Sub Application_Idle(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)  
    ' TODO: Restart the 10-minute timer.
End Sub

' This assumes your TenMinuteTimer object has an Expire event.  Do what works for you instead.
Private Sub TenMinuteTimer_Expire(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TenMinuteTimer.Expire
    ' TODO: Close the application safely.
End Sub
```

The only issue with this is if the user starts an action that takes longer than 10 minutes, it will raise `Application.Idle` after `TenMinuteTimer.Expire`.  If you expect this may happen, be sure to disable the TenMinuteTimer before executing long-running code and enable it again afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using the Application.Idle event; like so:

```
Private Sub Application_Idle(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) 

    MessageBox.Show("You are in the Application.Idle event.")

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

I personally recommend the Windows implementation because you then don't have to worry about all of the various scenarios that could occur:

Do you shut the app down or leave it open?

What if the user has a prompt (message box) displayed on the screen?

If you shut the app down, how do you handle work in progress?

If you don't shut the app down, how do you inform the user and then, if a different user wants to log in, how do you gracefully rollback the previous user's info?

If a different user wants to log in, how you can prevent them from seeing any sensitive information that the previous user may have left on the screen?

However, if you do want to proceed with this, then your best bet is to hook into the standard windows message pipeline through IMessageFilter. [Here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/Application_Idle.aspx) is a decent article on how to use this.

Answer (score 0):

You could periodically check the coordinates of the cursor and see if they have changed since the last check. After a certain amount of checks without any change, the application would then close. Probably not the best method, but it is definitely an option.